# Database logic based on fields in database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a pretty standard table in my schema..

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "title"
  t.text     "sellersku"
  t.text     "sku"
  t.text     "price"
  t.boolean  "is_variant"
  t.string   "variations"
...
end
```

I'm pulling this data from an API and populating my database with it..

Some of these products are related to one another by their "sku". For example, if the first 5 characters in one product's sku match the sku of another product then they are "variations" and I would like to put that sku in the variations field, and probably mark the "is_variant" field as true.

How would I do this? I'm assuming some logic in my product model, but I don't even know where to start?? Been googling for awhile and not even sure what to google??

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column `sku5` where you can store first five chars of the full `sku`. Whenever you need to find associated products, you can search them by joining `sku5` fields.

You can generalize this case by adding more categories if `sku5` is not enough to fully describe your system.